# Problema con las convenciones de nombres de eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hola el problema que tengo es que no entiendo como van las convenciones de nombres eloquent cuando la clave primary no esta definido como por ej. (user_id) por que a lo que lei es que en los modelos al momento de relacionar ya sea con hasmany, belongsto, etc..... este ya lo entiende que la clave foranea estas como user_id o algo asi, la verdad es que no entendi, me confundi y pues no se como es la cosa para relacionar modelos cuando las llaves foraneas y primarias no siguen esa convención y estan definidas con otros nombres, si alguien pudiera explicarme con un ejemplo practico de por lo menos tres modelos relacionados en donde las claves primarias y foraneas tengan otros nombres, ya que la base de datos con la que estoy trabajando no sigue esas convenciones que laravel indica, grasias.

aqui dejo tres de los modelos q estoy usando 
modelo Proveedores

```
class Proveedores extends Model
{
    protected $table='proveedores';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_proveedor';
    protected $fillable=['cod_proveedor',    //llave primaria
                         'proveedor',
                         'cod_cooperativa',
                         'cod_origen'];

    public function liqui_p(){
      return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_proveedor_li');
    }
}
```

modelo liquidaciones

```
class Liquidaciones extends Model
{
    protected $table='liquidaciones';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_columna';
    protected $fillable = ['cod_columna',     //llave primaria
                           'cod_liquidacion',
                           'clave_muestra',
                           'fecha_ingreso',
                           'fecha_liquidacion',
                           'cod_proveedor_li',       //llave foranea
                           'particula',
                           'cod_cooperativa',
                           'cod_transportista_li',      //llave foranea
                           'observaciones',
                           'cod_origen',
                           'cheque',
                           'anticipo_',
                           'cheque_',
                           'trans_1',
                           'TMB',
                           'TARA',
                           'HUM',
                           'TMH',
                           'TMS',
                           'IMSUR_ZN',
                           'ZINC',
                           'IMSUR_DM',
                           'PLATA_DM',
                           'IMSUR_PLOMO',
                           'PLOMO',
                           'CLIENTE_ZN',
                           'PRECIO_ZN',
                           'CLIENTE_DM',
                           'PRECIO_AG',
                           'CLIENTE_PLOMO',
                           'PRECIO_PLOMO',
                           'monto',
                           'mas_transporte',
                           'importe_total',
                           'estado',
                           'debe',
                           'cod_grupo_liquidacion',
                           'usuario_ingreso',
                           'usuario_liquidacion',
                           'costo_dolar',
                           'plataforma',
                           'triturado',
                           'pago_transporte',
                           'cod_persona',
                           'devuelto'];
    public function transporte_(){
       return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\Transportista','cod_transportista');
     }

    public function proveedor_(){
      return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\Proveedores','cod_proveedor');
    }
}
```

modelo transportista

```
class Transportista extends Model
{
    protected $table='transportista';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_transportista';
    protected $fillable=['cod_transportista',      //llave primaria
                         'transportista',
                         'cod_placa'];

    public function trans_li(){
      return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_transportista_li');
    }
}
```

luego hago el uso de tinker para ver si estan bien relacionadas
y quiero ver las liquidaciones que tiene un proveedor pero no me sale haciendo esto

```
>>> $use=IMSUR\Proveedores::where('cod_proveedor','6869')->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#730
     all: [
       IMSUR\Proveedores {#731
         cod_proveedor: 6869,
         proveedor: "QUENTASI GERONIMO",
         cod_cooperativa: 1087,
         cod_origen: 5,
       },
     ],
   }


>>> $use->liqui_p;
PHP error:  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$liqui_
p on line 1
```

me sale este error alguien que me pueda explicar que estoy haciendo mal , grasias.

Comment: Si agregas por ejemplo la estructura o nombres de las columnas de tus tablas, lo que has intentado y los errores obtenidos; entonces tu pregunta tiene mejores posibilidades de ser respondida, considero además que en lugar de agregar un ejemplo puedes añadir también el código de tus modelos y de ahí partimos para auxiliarte; checa [ask]

Comment: Pues el error indica que tratas de acceder a una propiedad en tu objeto que no existe, si revisas la salida en tinker ahí no existe la propiedad que quieres leer

Comment: pero donde esta el error ? debo asumir que el error esta en la forma como estoy relacionando pero no se donde mi base de datos que uso no sigue las convenciones de laravel y es por eso que estoy declarando la llave foranea al momento de relacionar los modelos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error por el que preguntas al final y el cual agregaste luego de mi repuesta, es porque estas intentando usar el método del modelo en una collección, y dicho método únicamente puede ser utilizado en un objeto en específico, no en una collección.

En base al código que agregaste en la ultima edición de tu pregunta tienes dos opciones para poder acceder a la propiedad del modelo:

```
$use = IMSUR\Proveedores::where('cod_proveedor','6869')->get()->first()
```

ó

```
$use = IMSUR\Proveedores::find('6869')
```

luego

```
$use->liqui_p;
```

Recuerda que este método tambien te devolverá una collección.

Si aparece un nuevo error por favor formula una nueva pregunta, ya que la interrogante planteada acerca de las convenciones ya fue respondida.

Comment: Por favor considera no publicar múltiples respuestas, si el OP modificó su duda  entonces lo mas conveniente es editar tu aportew y agregar o quitar según convenga, por otro lado no me queda claro como va a acceder a un valor que al menos yo no veo se *pinte* en la salida de datos que el muestra

Comment: grasias jose-arita asiendo la prueva en tinker si me funciono

Comment: Consideré oportuno públicar una nueva repuesta debido a que no me era permitido modificar mucho la respuesta anterior y la pregunta tuvo un gran cambio.

En la parte final de la pregunta realizada reivinbonshueder está probando sus modelos en Tinker (consola de Artisan).

Answer (score 1):

Si la base de datos con la que estás trabajando no sigue las convenciones de Laravel puedes indicarle a Eloquent cual es el nombre del campo de la llave foránea que debe buscar. En el modelo, cuando se declara la relación de la tabla hijo a la tabla padre, el primer parámetro indica el modelo referenciado; puedes agregar un segundo parámetro que indica el nombre de la columna de llave foránea.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

Las tablas de la base de datos no siguen la convenciones del nombre de la tabla, el id y la llave foránea.

Tabla `post` (el nombre correcto según las convenciones sería `posts` y llave primaria debe llamarse `id` en lugar de `pk`)

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pk         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| message    | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Tabla `comment` (el nombre correcto según las convenciones sería `comments`, llave primaria debe llamarse `id` en lugar de `pk` y el nombre correcto de la llave foránea sería `post_id` en lugar de `reference`)

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pk         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| message    | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reference  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Para las tablas descritas los modelos quedan de la siguiente manera:

Post

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'post';

    protected $primaryKey = 'pk';

    protected $fillable = ['message'];


    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'reference');
    }

}
```

Comment

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comment';

    protected $fillable = ['message'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'pk';


    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'reference');
    }

}
```

Adicionalmente puedes agregar el campo `reference` si quieres crear un comentario que de una vez se relacione al `post` por medio del atributo `pk`

```
protected $fillable = ['message', 'reference'];
```

Comment: seguí tu ejemplo pero no me salio deje tres de mis modelos en la parte de arriba y el error que me arroja al momento de usar tinker para ver si mis relaciones de modelos estaban bien